# PHP implode's strangely adds white chars to its output - why?

Tags: php, implode

I have very, very odd problem with PHP's implode function. It surprisingly adds some white characters (spaces) to one of array's elements.

Here is my code:

```
$cities = array(...,5792753,...);

$where .= ' AND gr.geo_city IN(' . implode(',', $cities) . ') ';

//it displays something like: ... AND gr.geo_city IN(...,5         792753,...)
//but it should display: ... AND gr.geo_city IN(...,5792753,...) 
//PLEASE NOTE SPACES IN THE EXAMPLE ABOVE!!
echo $where;
```

I have done some debugging and it seems the original values do not contain any white chars. Here is the code I've used to check it:

```
foreach($cities as $ct)
{
  if(strpos($ct,'792753') !== FALSE)
    echo $ct;//it displays 5792753, not 5...792753
}
```

Why does it add these spaces there? Is it some known bug of the implode function?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure those characters don't exist in your original array?

Comment: It doesn't do that. Probably just some (hidden) chars in the string.

Comment: can we get the original array? and the previous value of `$where`

Comment: Strange? Implode does nothing strange. In case it does, SO is not the right site for bug reports. So I think this needs some basic debugging first.

Comment: Give us the result of var_dump($cities) please.

Comment: Sorry mate, I have edited my question. Please read it. Thanks

Comment: Result of var_dump is: ... [32765]=> string(7) "5792753"...

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly have those characters in your original array values. As the commenters have said, `implode()` does nothing strange... Check your data again for hidden tabs or spaces, or other whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure there are no whitespaces, better strip them with some php functions (str_replace, trim, or reg_exp functions).
Implode does not add anything but the given separator.